# Show the eigenvalues of this submatrix are all less than $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, correlation, positive-definite

Let $C$ be a positive definite correlation matrix partitioned as

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
I_{k_1} & A \\
A' & I_{k_2} \end{bmatrix}$$

How can I show that the eigenvalues of $AA'$ are all less than $1$?

Comment: You can do a Schur complement argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness) of the lower-right entry, we see that $C$ is positive definite if and only if $I_{k_2} - AA'$ is positive definite. This occurs if and only if the eigenvalues of $AA'$ are less than $1$.

Comment: Thank you. The last part is because $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $1-\lambda$ is an eigenvaue of $I-A$ right?

Comment: @Alphie Exactly